# VIM CtrlP - Procurando arquivos com o mesmo nome

Tags: linux, vim

[image: database.yml no NERDTree]

[image: digitando o nome do arquivo database no CtrlP]

Estou com uma dificuldade na utilização do plugin CtrlP do VIM, no caso tenho dois arquivos com o nome "database", porem o CtrlP só acha um deles como apresentado na imagem.
Estou usando a seguinte configuração no meu .vimrc para o CtrlP:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -i --nocolor --nogroup --hidden
```

Alguém saberia o porque dele achar só um dos arquivos?

Comment: Reabri a pergunta porque uso de ferramentas usadas para programação faz parte do escopo.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Caso você tenha criado o arquivo recentemente pelo vim, você tem que atualizar o cache do CtrlP, para isso pressione 'F5' durante a busca, e veja se o resultado muda.

Comment: Oi, eu dei um tempo no vim, porem a alguns dias atras eu voltei a usar com o neo vim e esta tudo ok agora, obrigado!